# Rails 4 - When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting the following error?

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

The form:

```
    <%= form_for([current_user, current_user.suggestions.build]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :category %>:
        <%= f.select :category, ['Startup', 'Cars', 'Kids', 'Food', 'Other'] %> <br>
        <%= f.text_area :suggestion %><br>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit Suggestion' %>
    <% end %>
```

SuggestionController:

```
  def create
    @suggestion = current_user.suggestions.create(suggestion_params)
  end

  private
    def suggestion_params
      params.require(:suggestion).permit(:suggestion, :category)
      redirect_to shirts_path
    end
```

ApplicationController:

```
  helper_method :current_user

  private

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`suggestion_params` is returning the last line of the method `redirect_to shirts_path`, which `current_user.suggestions.create` can't accept because it isn't acceptable data.

The redirect should be in `create` method:

```
def create
    @suggestion = current_user.suggestions.create(suggestion_params)
    redirect_to shirts_path
end

private
  def suggestion_params
    params.require(:suggestion).permit(:suggestion, :category)
  end
```

Comment: omg, that was a dumb mistake on my part.  Thanks for the help!